# gdb nexti command not displaying line of source code

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I set a break in main then run the program (C code) but when I nexti all that is displayed is:

```
0x0stuff in main ()
0x0stuff in main ()
...
```

Instead of :

```
0x0stuff       for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
8              printf("Hello, world!\n");
```

How can I make gdp display the source line when using nexti?

Comment: What version of gdb are you using? gdb 7.9 does display the source line with `nexti`.

Comment: That is probably the issue I have 7.4

Comment: Did you include debugging information like line-numbers? How did you build?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. I upgraded to 7.7 and now it is working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`nexti` stes through one machine instruction, not one line of source code.  You want `step` or `next` for a line of source code.  It is worth reading the [documentation](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_37.html) carefully to see the difference.

Comment: I don't think OP has any misunderstanding between next and nexti.